# Which devices supply input signals for transistors in a computer?

Tags: transistors, computer-architecture

In a computer, I understand that the transistors are used to make up logic gates. For each transistor, there is a current (voltage) that controls the base terminal with the logic "low/high voltage".

I wonder how the transistor get the input signal? Which device supplies the signal "low/high" to the base terminal of a transistor in a computer, and how it is done when for example I push the "A" key on the keyboard?

Comment: For a keyboard the source of the signal is your finger pushing a button. For a network adapter, it's a transistor in whatever computer you're networked to. So it depends.

Comment: Other transistors!

Comment: @user1850479: Hi, thanks for your comment. Could you please explain me a little bit how the action of pushing the button can be transformed to be a "on/off" signal for the transistor ? Thanks!

Comment: A button on a keyboard is a switch - it will produce and on/off signal when pushed or released.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge when the button is pressed it completes a circuit - that's what buttons do. They can wire one to a transistor so when it's pressed it completes the circuit that activates the transistor. If this is unfamiliar to you, it seems like you might want to study basic electronic circuits some more, including basic transistor circuits.

Comment: A button is a device that generates an on/off signal when pushed.  You can open up a specific button to see how it works, but usually at some level two pieces of metal are made to touch each other, causing current to flow between them.

Answer (score 4):

I have shown below in four steps how a button press is converted to a transistor output voltage. The schematics are conceptual; if you use MOSFET instead BJT, just remove the base resistors. Try each of the schematics in both states (*closed* and *open*) of the button; you can set them from the SW *parameters* window of CircuitLab by hovering the mouse over the interesting circuit points to see the voltages and currents.

Note that the final circuit is not exactly a keyboard computer circuit but a simpler transistor circuit that shows how the two states of a key ("pressed" and "released") are converted to two values of voltage - "low" (0 V) and "high" (+5 V).

### STEP 1: Pressure into resistance

Keyboard keys are electrical buttons (switches) with two states.

**When they are "closed"** ("on"), they have low resistance. If they are "ideal" (perfect), we assume that their resistance is zero.  Mechanical switches such as keyboard buttons can be considered as such (by the way, you can experiment with the closed switch resistance in the schematics below by setting it in the SW *parameters* window).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGKxfj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**When they are "open"** ("off"), they have high resistance. If they are "ideal" (perfect), we assume that their resistance is infinite.  Mechanical switches such as keyboard buttons can be considered as such.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgoZzV.png)</sup>

### STEP 2: Resistance into voltage

Electronic devices, especially computers, work with voltages. Therefore, we need to convert the switch state (resistance) to a voltage. For this purpose, we have to pass current through the switch and take the voltage across it. This current can be produced by connecting a resistor R1 to the positive terminal of the power supply Vcc. Figuratively speaking, R1 tries to "pull up" the upper SW terminal to Vcc; hence the name "pull-up resistor".

From another viewpoint, the two elements (R1 and SW) in series form a *voltage divider* where the two elements "fight" each other - R1 "pulls" the midpoint up while SW "pulls" it down. Who wins in this "tug of war" game depends on the ratio of their resistances.

**When SW is closed**, it is "stronger" and wins the "game" - the output voltage is 0 V. There is current I = Vcc/R1 (Ohm's law) flowing through SW but there is no voltage drop (Vout1 = I.Rsw = I.0 = 0) across it. Let's look at this case in more detail because it is fundamental to electrical circuits.

In a circuit of two resistors R1 and R2 in series (the so-called "voltage divider"), the same current I flows through both resistors. Voltage drops appear across them, which are inversely proportional to the resistances. Therefore, the midpoint is "moved" to the source rail to which the  resistor with lower resistance is connected. Figuratively speaking, it is "stronger" than the other resistor because it manages to "pull" the midpoint towards itself. Here this resistor (closed switch SW) has zero resistance and is therefore much "stronger" than the other resistor R1; so the midpoint has reached the negative rail (ground).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqHdgi.png)</sup>

**When SW is open**, R1 is stronger (since the SW resistance is infinite) and wins the "game" - the output voltage is 5 V. This contradicts human intuition because there is resistance, but it does not prevent the Vcc voltage from appearing at the output. The reason is that there is no load connected in parallel to SW, the voltmeter has infinite resistance (open circuit) and SW is open. So the circuit is broken in the section between R1 and ground, and there is no current flowing through R1; therefore there is no voltage drop across it. As a result, the entire voltage of 5 V is applied across the switch (voltmeter) and appears as an output voltage Vout1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Wsnr.png)</sup>

Thus the two states (resistances) of SW are converted into two states of voltage - 0 V and 5 V, and can be processed by transistors.

### STEP 3: Voltage into voltage

Let's now apply the output voltage Vout1 to the base of a bipolar transistor Q1. A BJT is a device with a "nasty" input that behaves like a forward-biased diode. So, if we connect Vout1 directly to Q1's base, its input "base-emitter diode" will fix Vout1 at 0.7 V (you can observe it by setting R2 = 0 in its *parameters* window). This can cause problems if there are other transistors connected to Vout1. So, let's insert a "base resistor" R2 in series to decouple the base from Vout1.

Q1 acts as an "electronic switch" which in the same way (through the "pull-up" resistor R3) produces an output voltage Vout2.

**When SW is closed**, it absorbs the entire current produced by the help of R1. There is no base current flowing and Q1 is like an open switch ("off", as it is customary to say).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft0DT4.png)</sup>

**When SW is open**, the R1 current is diverted through R2 and it enters the base. So the transistor is like a closed switch ("on" or "saturated", as they say). Like SW above, it absorbs the entire current Ic1 = Vcc/R3 produced by the help of R3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcFxjA.png)</sup>

It is interesting to compare with the analogous case from Step 2 above (open SW) where there was no load connected in parallel to SW. Here, the base resistor R2 serves as a load that draws current from R1 so there is a voltage drop across it. As a result, the output voltage Vout1 across SW drops to 4.6 V (hover the mouse over the midpoint to see it). From another viewpoint, R1 and R2 form another voltage divider, and Vout1 is decreased.

### STEP 4: Voltage into another voltage

We can go further and apply the Q1's output voltage Vout2 through a base resistor R4 to the base of another transistor Q2 so:

**When SW is closed**, Q2's output voltage Vout3 will be zero (you can see why by hovering the mouse over the schematic).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPBtP4.png)</sup>

**When SW is open**, Vout3 will be 5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3hN7G.png)</sup>

The Q2's output voltage produced through the "pull-up" resistor R5 can be applied to the next transistor... and so on and so forth…

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer! In your schemas, I see the symbol V_cc 5V, can I understand it as the electricity (somewhat in "standby" mode) which always exists when the power is ON, and it is supplied by the PSU (power supply unit) of the computer ? If i'm wrong, please correct me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, Thanks for the response. Vcc is the supply voltage of this transistor circuit. The index "cc" means that this voltage supplies the **c**ollector of the transistor (through the collector resistor). If the transistor is not a BJT but a MOSFET, then it is called Vdd; "dd" means that this voltage supplies the **d**rain (through the drain resistor). This is not exactly a keyboard computer circuit but a simpler transistor circuit that shows how the two states of a key ("pressed" and "released") are converted to two values of voltage - "low" (0 V) and "high" (+5 V).

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have another little question please, in the step 3, i can see that the current will always flow to the base of the transistor Q1 (because the branch of SW1 seems to me irrelevant). In this case, which is the role of the SW1 ? Thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, Hi! I have inserted additional schematics and now I will add explanations to them. Then we can discuss these so interesting questions...

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. I have 2 questions of Step 2 please. 1) In the case  S_w is closed, as it has Zero resistence, then i think it should be "weaker" than R1 and there should be current flows through S_w (no resistence to prevents electricity), as opposed to your statements. 2) In case S_w is opened, maybe i'm stupid but why we can say "there is no load connected, so there is no current flowing through R1 and therefore there is no voltage drop across it" ? because I see that it is a closed circuit, the current flow from + to -, no load is indeed needed to have current flow through R1. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @InTheSearchForKnowledge! Your questions are about fundamental circuit properties and deserve to be asked in separate questions. I have added more details to my explanations in Step 2 and Step 3 (read these parts again to see them). Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help!! I have always a question of Step 2 please. Can you please explain me what does it mean by saying "stronger" ? "Stronger" is stated in the sense that it has lower resistence ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the question is stupid and it takes time for you to answer it, could you please suggest me an article/book that I should read to understand it ? Thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, Understanding (not just learning) circuits requires specific means; analogies are one of them. So, in this particular case, we imagine the two resistors as "ropes" or, more precisely, as two "springs" through which the players in the "tag of war" game pull the middle point. The lower the resistance, the stronger the spring that represents it. "Arm wrestling" is another analogy of this arrangement. You can find more (suitable for you) analogies to visualize the operation of this circuit...

Comment: I can only suggest you visit the sites where I explain(ed) circuits in this *heuristic* way; I have placed links to them on my profile page.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your kindness!

Comment: Hi, I have a question. In the step 2, why do we denote the Voltage flow through the Switch (S_W) $V_{out}$ when I see that the circuit is in fact closed. So I expect that the final point of the circuit should be the negative polar (as the current flows from positive to negative)? Therefore, should I understand the $V_{out}$ as the voltage between 2 polars of the circuit, which is always 5V... It seems that I am wrong somewhere. Please correct me. Thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, When SW is open, the supply voltage Vcc is connected through the resistor R1 to the output where the voltmeter Vout1 is connected as a load. Since the voltmeter has infinite resistance (open circuit), there is no current flowing through and no voltage drop across R1. So, the entire voltage (5 V) appears at the output and is applied to the voltmeter. When SW is closed, it shunts the output (short connection); so there is no output voltage applied to the voltmeter. In the circuit of a transistor switch, the transistor acts as the mechanical switch SW.

Comment: Hi, in the Step 2, by saying "output", do you mean the "arrow" part ? So is it true that the current flow from the + polar to the "dot (.)" between the big arrow in the right corner of the graph and the "-" polar, then it flows in 2 directions: 1) to the negative polar and 2) through the arrow. Is it true please ? Thanks!!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, The output is the voltage across the mechanical switch (and voltmeter). I have added more arrows to show the full current path. Similarly, the output of transistor amplifier stages is the voltage across the collector-emitter part.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kindness so far! I still don't understand where electricity flows. As I understand electricity flows from + to - polars. For example, in the Step 2 graphiques, is it the case ? or in this case, the electricity flows from + to the big arrow in the under right corner, and it does not flow through the - (negative) polar ? I'm confused......, sorry and thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, In the first schematic of STEP 2, the current comes out of the Vcc positive terminal, passes through the upper conductor, resistor R1, closed switch SW, the bottom conductor and finally enters the Vcc negative terminal. Maybe the ground symbol bothers you? Just ignore it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help so far. Can you explain me why should there be steps 3 and 4 ? It seems to me resistance to voltage is enough right ? because the transistor can already work with an input voltage (i.e. V_out1). Thank you very much!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, They illustrate how the switch voltage is further processed by transistors. Remember that you have asked, "I wonder how the transistor get the input signal?"

Answer (score 2):

Within the intricate realm of computing, transistors often acquire input stimuli from fellow transistors, elaborate integrated circuits or sophisticated microcontrollers. Imagine your fingertips striking the "A" key on the keyboard; a cascade of events unfolds. A microcontroller nestled within the keyboard's labyrinthine circuitry detects the keystroke, decrypting the signal and dispatching the appropriate binary message to the ever-vigilant processor of your computer. Along this journey, myriad transistors ensconced in logic gates engage with fluctuating voltage signals, deftly executing the indispensable operations that bring the digital world to life.

Answer (score 1):

The transistors will most likely receive their input signal from the transistors that are "behind" them, which are changing states due to something else entirely. Some transistors might run multiple times as well for one task, and it entirely depends on the part of the computer in question. Of course as someone else mentioned, a click of the mouse or a press of a key would result in some onslaught of changing transistor states in order to run the program or instructions needed. I believe this is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the transistor receives its control signal from… another transistor. Larger functions are built up from multiple transistors linked together.

For example, the not-AND (NAND) function is composed of four field-effect transistors, or FETs. Try one out, [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-cmosnand.html). As it so happens, you can build any kind of digital machine based just on this one gate by linking  multiples of them together. In reality, complex functions use a variety of gates and specialized transistor-based functions.

Anyway, to your specific key press example. Say you’re using a text editor. The ‘A’ press will get processed in several steps:

- key press, switch closes
- Keyboard IC scans the keys, sees the closure via an input pin

Let’s talk about this for a moment. The switch is electrically connected to the IC input pin. The change in switch state changes the logic level to the pin. This logic level controls the pin’s receiving gate (input buffer), which in turn forwards the signal to the chip internals.

Continuing:

- Keyboard IC decodes the key position and converts that to a key code

A keyboard IC is a small microprocessor by itself, running software.

- Keyboard IC sends the code to the host computer

The IC and host use a serial link. The key code formatted for that link, converted to electrical pulses and placed on the wire.

- Host computer receives the key code and processes it

Typically, key codes are received and placed in a memory buffer.

- Host editing application gets the key code, converts it to the ‘A’ character, inserts it into your text file and updates the text display.

Most of this happens within ICs, at a transistor-to-transistor level controlled by software. There’s two points where this isn’t true:

- when the key is scanned
- when the key code is sent from one IC to another

In the first case, some kind of physical phenomenon is converted to an electrical signal that the keyboard IC can understand.

In the second case, the IC is converting its internal signals to one that can be sent from one place to in other.

In other words… user interface and communication.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have made some assumptions that aren't necessarily correct. For one, the assumption that in a logic circuit the base of a bipolar junction transistor is the input. This is not always (and today rarely) true.

Modern computers use microprocessors made with [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) technology, so their transistors are MOSFETs which have a gate instead of a base. Early computers used [vacuum tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum-tube_computer) with a grid for input.

A CMOS NAND gate might look a bit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd2jBt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even with bipolar logic gates such as [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) the input signal doesn't have to go to the base, a TTL gate can use the emitter of a transistor as the input. For example this is a typical TTL inverter circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmSaA9.png)</sup>

A TTL NAND gate uses pretty much the same circuit, except that Q1 is made with [two or more separate emitter junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-emitter_transistor).

In all of these the logic circuits are driven by a [clock circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal). It is this clock that allows the computer to execute instructions in sequence. As the clock signal goes high and low it triggers gates and flip-flops to transfer data between buses, registers, memory and arithmetic logic, and perform logical operations on the data.
Almost everything the computer does depends on clock signals, if you really want to understand how computers work at the hardware level, you need to understand how the clock works.